# OOP Confusion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I want to do something like this.  Here is one class:

```
module MyModule
  class ClassOne
    def initialize
      @chain = []
    end

    def add_type_one(thing1, thing2)
      @chain << thing1 + thing2
    end

    def add_type_two(thing3, thing4)
      @chain << thing3 + thing4
    end

    def sanitize
      @chain.join(" ").gsub("this", "that")
    end
  end
 end
```

Here is another class:

```
module MyModule
  class ClassTwo
    def initialize
      @other_chain = []
    end

    def add_more(thingA, thingB)
      @other_chain << thingA + thingB
    end

    def add_even_more(thingC, thingD)
      @other_chain << thingC + thingD
    end

    def run
      system('program #{@chain} #{@other_chain}')
    end
  end
 end
```

Then I'd like to call these methods like so:

```
a = ClassOne.new
a.add_type_one("I", "Want")
a.add_type_two("These", "Methods")
a.sanitize

b = ClassTwo.new
b.add_more("And", "Variables")
b.add_even_more("To", "Work together")
b.run
```

What must be done to get a final output of

```
system('program I Want These MethodsAndVariablesToWork together')
```

The point of this example is simply that I do not have access to ClassOne methods or variables within ClassTwo. The

```
 b.run
```

needs to take in some message or output from ClassOne. I know that instance variables aren't accessible outside of the instance of the class, and I know that I could use a global variable or a constant and that could work - but this is not the best practice. I don't know why this still isn't clear to me. I'm missing a small piece of this puzzle. Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean `I do not have access to ClassOne methods or variables within ClassTwo`? Do you have access to instance `a`?

Comment: @chain was created in a ClassOne so when ClassTwo wants to access it, it's not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you had multiple ClassOne instances. How would ClassTwo even know which instance to use?

You could approach this problem by injecting an instance of ClassOne into ClassTwo. Like so

```
a = ClassOne.new
a.add_type_one("I", "Want")
a.add_type_two("These", "Methods")
a.sanitize

b = ClassTwo.new(a)
b.add_more("And", "Variables")
b.add_even_more("To", "Work together")
b.run
```

And then access the instance variables of ClassOne from within ClassTwo.

Comment: This depends on `ClassOne` having a simple method for getting the important data so it can be shared.

Comment: Is that it? Does my initialize for ClassTwo now take in a parameter?

Comment: Actually, looking at it further, maybe I need ClassThree who's sole purpose is to take in ClassOne and ClassTwo instances?  That one could be the "runner"?

Comment: Sure, you could do that.  Or if the runner doesn't have to store any state, it could just be a method.  Like: `module Runner; def self.run(a, b); end; end`

Answer (score 2):

Have it in the following way so that the ClassOne is accessible by the ClassTwo,

```
module MyModule
   class ClassOne
   attr_reader :chain
      def initialize
         @chain = []
      end

      def add_type_one(thing1, thing2)
         @chain << thing1 + thing2
      end

      def add_type_two(thing3, thing4)
         @chain << thing3 + thing4
      end

      def sanitize
         @chain = @chain.join(" ").gsub("this", "that")
      end
   end

   class ClassTwo
      def initialize(obj)
         @classOne = obj
         @other_chain = []
      end

      def add_more(thingA, thingB)
         @other_chain << thingA + thingB
      end

      def add_even_more(thingC, thingD)
         @other_chain << thingC + thingD
      end

      def run
         system('program #{@classOne.chain} #{@other_chain.join}')
      end
   end
end
```